# Getting scimitars to be light without losing class levels?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, weapons

I was trying to make a druid/fey bloodrager who wielded dual scimitars. I didn't know how I could get past the extra two weapon penalties for scimitars. So how could I make scimitars light without taking the dervish class?

In response to comments.
I'd prefer it be something part of the character, if that is what "resources" mean in it.  also want to be able to get it as early as I could.

Comment: So, just to be sure I've understood correctly: You want it to be intrinsic to your character (i.e. not a weapon property or magic item of any kind), but not require class levels? So you're pretty much looking solely for feats?

Comment: It seemed clear to me he is asking how to make scimitars light without using multi-classing into dervish. Why are resources even at question? Wouldn't a proper answer provide for any resources that can make this scenario happen so long as that resource was not multiclassing?

Comment: @DanceSC If people answered before the question was clarified, answers might say something like "This magic item does exactly what you want." Only to have the OP say "Actually, I don't want an item, I want it to be part of my character." If we clarify first, we can hopefully prevent that.

Comment: @Miniman you've hit the nail on the head

Answer (score 12):

<s>There is no good way to have *what the book calls a scimitar* that is a light weapon.</s><sup>1</sup> Burning feats or taking −2 attack penalties for wielding an undersized scimitar are ridiculously painful for something that should be very simple.

Instead, take the stats of a kukri, call it a “light scimitar,” and you’re good to go.<sup>2</sup> The rules of the game never define that the game-item called “kukri” has to *look* like the real-world weapon by that name.<sup>3</sup> It’s just a bundle of stats with a label so it can be conveniently referred to in the rules and can be balanced against other weapons. How your equipment *looks*, as an extension of how your *character* looks, is really up to you. And what your character decides to *call* that item is **definitely** up to you.

And a kukri *is* the light version of the scimitar: slashing damage with 18-20/×2 critical threat range. The damage die is *slightly* smaller (on average, 1 damage point), but aside from this, the weapons are nigh-identical. Losing 1 damage is a *lot* less costly than any other option available to you.

And there is no good reason why you should have to waste resources on getting to describe your character the way you wish to.

---

1. <sup>I was mistaken; [@Barillas found a pretty solid one in the form of *effortless lace*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/62640/4563), which should cover the requirements for most purposes. Not an intrinsic part of the character, but there don’t appear to be any of those.</sup>
2. <sup>This may fail if you have particular feats or class features for *what the book calls a scimitar* – if you were given a choice, you can always choose *what you call a kukri and I call a light scimitar* for feats like Weapon Focus (and thus may want to wield *two* of these light scimitars, rather than a scimitar and a light scimitar), but other options may not give you a choice. In this case, you really do need *what the book calls a scimitar* **unless** your DM agrees to change it. I feel that in almost-all cases, a reasonable DM should have no problem with this, but that’s a conversation you’ll have to have.</sup>
3. <sup>Though DMs do probably have to draw the line somewhere; saying your kukri looks like, and is called, a *light warhammer* or something, probably isn’t going to fly, since something that looks like a warhammer shouldn’t be dealing slashing damage. But saying your “kukri” looks like a lighter scimitar is entirely reasonable, seeing as the two weapons are so similar in the first place.</sup>

Comment: In my opinion this is the best choice.
Even if he loses Weapon Focus, it is still only -1 to attacks and damage compared to his medium scimitar.

Comment: @ShadowKras And simply using two “light scimitars,” losing 1 damage from both, allows you to have one set of chosen-weapon feats like Weapon Focus *et al.*, which may be a better choice.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your character's background, you could consider [Effortless Lace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/effortless-lace)
if, for instance, you come from a clan of giant hunters or something. While the item itself isn't "part of your character", it would certainly be something that a giant hunter would be very familiar with as part of their training.

The part of the item description I would want to draw your attention to is this:

> If the weapon is wielded by a creature whose size matches that of the weapon's intended wielder, the weapon is treated as a light melee weapon when determining whether it can be used with Weapon Finesse, as well as with any feat, spell, or special weapon ability that can be used in conjunction with light weapons.

Because a scimitar is being wielded by a **creature whose size matches that of the weapon's intended wielder**, it would make the scimitar now count as a light weapon.

However, bear in mind the specific requirements listed there. It **does** say that it becomes treated as a light weapon for the sake of any feat that can be used in conjunction with light weapons. In my mind, this would mean things like Two-Weapon Fighting, which is what you're wanting from your description. This **does not** mean that the weapon actually **becomes** a light weapon, so be very careful with what other items and abilities you pick up that may be dependent on that.

Comment: I always forget about this silly thing, but it is close to a perfect answer here.

Comment: KRyan-sama noticed me. *swoon*

Answer (score 0):

You can craft a **Small Scimitar**, if you really want to use a light scimitar instead of a kukri for instance. That way the weapon is *small* for your character, but would be *medium* for a halfling, yet still fully qualifying for feats and two-weapon fighting.

Let me add that your damage dice will go one step down though, from D6 to D4. 
Also, as @I Can Chan pointed out, you still suffer -2 to attacks for wielding a weapon made for a different size.

Comment: In thought the rule that "one-handed weapons crafted for small characters count as light in the hands of medium ones" didn't exist in Pathfinder.

Comment: @GMJoe *Pathfinder* kept *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*'s `effort` [rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons).